# Swift - UITableView won't add data

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, crash

I have a UITableView and when I add data, it will only allow me to add one row in the UITableview even though I return goals.count for the amount of rows.

This is what I have.

```
@IBAction func myAddGoal(sender: AnyObject) {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter a Goal", message: "It can be anything you want!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    ac.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(nil)
    let submit = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .Default) { [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        let goal = ac.textFields![0] as UITextField
        self.submitGoal(goal.text)
    }
    ac.addAction(submit)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func submitGoal(goal: String){
    if goal == "" {
        println("textfield is empty")
    } else {
        goals.insert(goal, atIndex: 0)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        myTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        println(goals)
    }
}
```

I am able to add only ONE goal and it will animate into the UITableView. If I want to add another goal, it will not let me. The app crashes when I hit submit for a second goal entry.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return goals.count
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let object = goals[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = object

    mySwitch.on = false
    mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row as Int
    mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: "UISwitchUpdated", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch
    return cell

}
```

Comment: what is the crash message?

Comment: @rakeshbs It doesn't give a crash message. It doesn't actually crash. The simulator freezes and nothing will work if I want to add another goal.

Comment: Where does it freeze? Pause in the debugger and see what's going on.

Comment: @matt 0x10ad5229d:  popq   %rbp